# Open Telemetry Logger MDC auto-instrumentation

Tags: spring-boot, logback, open-telemetry, mdc

The following Open Telemetry starters have been added to the Spring Boot project (`v2.7.2`) to instrument the application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.1-alpha</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-jaeger-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.1-alpha</version>
</dependency>
```

Traces and spans are successfully exported to a Jaeger collector. The problem is those traces and spans cannot be correlated with log statements because logs don't contain the current `trace_id` and `span_id`.

By following [the documentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/logger-mdc-instrumentation.md) I added the `logging.pattern.level` property to `application.properties` but it seems like information about the current span is not injected into the logging event's MDC copy.

```
logging.pattern.level = trace_id=%mdc{trace_id} span_id=%mdc{span_id} trace_flags=%mdc{trace_flags} %5p
```

For example:

```
log.info(
    "traceId: {}, spanId: {}",
    Span.current().getSpanContext().getTraceId(),
    Span.current().getSpanContext().getSpanId());
```

> 2023-01-25 12:21:36.774 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO 34272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] h.c.DemoController  : traceId: 1bccb6a4fea8345026ca87a202f0091f, spanId: c59a5d44ee40cd2c

Have I missed anything?

Comment: MDC instrumentation only works with the Java agent. "The OTel Java agent injects ...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter` is missing this feature right now (version `1.22.1-alpha`), but it can be added very easily.

Firstly, [MDC Instrumentation for Logback](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation/logback/logback-mdc-1.0/library) dependency should be added to the project.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-logback-mdc-1.0</artifactId>
    <version>OPENTELEMETRY_VERSION</version>
  </dependency>
```

Then add a custom `logback.xml` configuration to the classpath, which will automatically inject context information from the span context to logging events.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!--    Default logback configuration    -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml"/>
    <!--   -->
    <appender name="OTEL" class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="OTEL"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Finally, add the property to `application.properties` (as mentioned in the question):

```
logging.pattern.level = trace_id=%mdc{trace_id} span_id=%mdc{span_id} trace_flags=%mdc{trace_flags} %5p
```